# How to render a visual on another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpf-controls, dispatcher

Im trying to render a canvas on another thread. Here is my attempt:

```
// returns path to exported image
private string exportToImage(double width, double height, Visual visual)
{
    var filename = string.Format(@"{0}.png", Guid.NewGuid());
    var tempFile = Path.Combine(tempDir, filename);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)rect.Right,
        (int)rect.Bottom, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);

    Thread RENDER_THREAD = new Thread(() => 
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            rtb.Render(visual);
        }));
    });
    RENDER_THREAD.Start();

    //endcode as PNG
    BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

    //save to memory stream
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    pngEncoder.Save(ms);
    ms.Close();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, ms.ToArray());
    return tempFile;
}
```

Im not getting any errors but the rendered result is an empty image. Is the instance of `rtb` in the main thread and the new thread the same?

**Edit**:
Here is my latest attempt.

I create the thread on a MouseUp event:

```
var curLayer = GetItemsPanel((canvasDataBinding.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(Binding_LayersListView.SelectedIndex)));
Thread RASTERIZE_THREAD = new Thread(() => { exportToImage(curLayer.ActualWidth, curLayer.ActualHeight, curLayer); });
RASTERIZE_THREAD.Start();
```

and here is my method the new thread uses:

```
void exportToImage(double width, double height, Visual visual)
{
    var filename = string.Format(@"{0}.png", Guid.NewGuid());
    var tempFile = Path.Combine(tempDir, filename);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)rect.Right,
        (int)rect.Bottom, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);

    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        rtb.Render(visual);
    }));

    //endcode as PNG
    BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

    //save to memory stream
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    pngEncoder.Save(ms);
    ms.Close();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, ms.ToArray());
}
```

So why does it tell me that *The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it* on `rtb.Render(visual)`? Im not calling exportToImage from anywhere else, so why is the Dispatcher not associated with the thread I created?

Edit:
I needed to create the RebderTargetBitmap inside Dispatcher.Invoke().

Comment: two problems! using dispatcher within the thread effectively make the thread useless, secondly there is no guarantee that thread completes before the result is used here `BitmapFrame.Create(rtb)`

Comment: I think I understand. So should I create a new thread on the exportToImage method, then use the dispatcher inside the method?

Comment: does it take too long to render? if no then thread is just an overhead, if yes then the effort is worth investing. secondly the method is synchronous as it needs a rendered file to return, so making the render function async will not help as the method has to wait till the render complete. in that case the method should return void.

Comment: @pushpraj Yes it takes long when the canvas that I want to render is populated with too many images, and if the dimensions of the canvas increases. So to make it asynchronous perhaps I can store the path of the rendered image to some shared buffer, then in the main thread periodically check the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a code how you can render the same in a thread and make it async

whole idea is

- serialize the visual into xaml string
- create a STA Thread
- then let thread deserialize the same.
- host the deserialized visual in a content control, and do Arrange etc.
- last but not the least, render it (taken from your code)

this code in not dependent on Dispatcher so it is able to run full async

```
    void exportToImage(double width, double height, Visual visual)
    {
        //this line can not be inside a thread because different thread owns the visual
        string visualData = XamlWriter.Save(visual);

        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var filename = string.Format(@"{0}.png", Guid.NewGuid());
                var tempFile = System.IO.Path.Combine("c:\\", filename);

                Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

                //create a host control to host the visual
                ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
                cc.Content = XamlReader.Parse(visualData);
                //call Arrange to let control perform layout (important)
                cc.Arrange(rect);

                RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)rect.Right,
                    (int)rect.Bottom, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);

                rtb.Render(cc);

                //endcode as PNG
                BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

                //save to memory stream
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

                pngEncoder.Save(ms);
                ms.Close();
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, ms.ToArray());
            });
        //STA is necessary for XamlReader.Parse, and proper rendering
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
    }
```

I have successfully tested this code to render some test visuals. but results may vary depending on how you use. as a guess bindings & raster images may have some issues, however in my tests it worked like a charm.

Comment: I got it to work on some of my visuals, but I cant get it to work on a canvas with multiple children (image controls). I read this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/b1aef630-bad2-41cc-b413-be6b12548e90/save-canvas-and-its-children-to-xaml-file and I dont think I can save my canvas. Any ideas?

Comment: for Canvas you may need to set the height and width explicitly on the canvas because default height width of canvas is 0. is it possible for you to share a working sample of your code, may I give a try.

Comment: I tried to simply my code as much as I could, here is the app.
http://www68.zippyshare.com/v/88730897/file.html

You only need to look at MainWindow.xaml and Xenoblend.cs

Comment: @Infodayne, I download the sample, I can see some images being saved on mouse up. how do I reproduce the issue you are facing?

Comment: If you increase the canvas size or if the dimensions of the image that is being draw is large, it takes too long to save the canvas, clear the canvas, then drawn the saved image to the canvas. Here is an example if the canvas is 256x256 http://i.minus.com/iFXnyYg3N3qjx.gif and if it is 2048x2048 http://i.minus.com/i5GId8iM8hU28.gif . I was thinking of rendering the canvas on another thread, so that the user wouldnt need to wait. Is it possible to use your async exportToImage method here? If not I'll accept your post as an answer, although it doesn't solve my issue, it addresses the title.

Comment: at 2048x2048 it is quite fast for me, but can see some lag when I make it 10000x10000. perhaps due to processor difference. secondly the code uses the dispatcher.invoke to render, so it is not async. serialization of canvas as suggested in answer did not work because the canvas items are data bound. at this point as an option you can remove data bindings from the primary layer and push images directly then the serialization will work and make it async. alternatively you may give a try using BeginInvoke on dispatcher with lower priority [see this](http://pastebin.com/DSgrpEhi)

Comment: @Infodayne, I did try to re-write your code to make it async, download the [TextureGenerator_WPF.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPTFpwZ3NuN0tLQmc/view?pli=1) and see if this helps. to change the texture size use the `CanvasSize` double value in the window resources.

Comment: Working great. I just need to make sure it doesn't clear any newly drawn images that haven't been rendered, but I can figure that out. Thanks a ton, I learn a lot.

Comment: @Infodayne, I am glad to be your assistance, you can always find me through my profile. last but not the least, happy coding :)