# Generate Png from UserControl in background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, async-await, task

I'm trying to generate png images from a background thread to prevent the UI from freezing up. I have a UserControl that I'm using to generate the visual. The problem is that it takes about 200ms per image, and I am unable to get it to run in the background.

To be clear I do not need to show the anything in the UI at all only generate a png to be stored in a database.

Here is the code that I tried putting in a task.

```cs
var c1 = await Task<byte[]>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var _TrimDesignerVM = new TrimDesignerVM(new Profile(line.CustomTrimInfo));
    _TrimDesignerVM.CanvasWidth = 520.0;
    _TrimDesignerVM.CanvasHeight = 520.0;
    _TrimDesignerVM.ZoomToFit();
    
    //System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.'
    var control = new Views.CustomTrimDetail(); //this is the line that throws an exception.
    control.DataContext = _TrimDesignerVM;
    control.Width = 742;
    control.Height = 520;
    control.Measure(new Size(742, 520));
    control.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(742, 520)));
    control.UpdateLayout();
    var rect = new Rect(control.RenderSize);
    var visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen()) dc.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(control), null, rect);
    var c = new byte[] { };
    double w = 742, h = 520, dpi = 96, scale = dpi / 96;
    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(w * scale), (int)(h * scale), dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Default);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(ms);
        contents = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return c;
});
```

Is it possible to do this without freezing the UI thread?

Comment: This answer might help. Basically you need to avoid the dispatcher and push visuals to the render thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945157/how-to-render-a-visual-on-another-thread

Comment: Doing background rendering might be easier using GDI, if that is an option. Also, have you checked if you can make the rendering faster? Pushing work to a background thread can be useful, but having work complete fast enough that it does not matter is often better.

Comment: Can I generate visuals on the background thread? For only one image it might not be a problem, but for multiple images I need a way to generate the visual without freezing the  UI.

Comment: Thanks @Dean Chalk, that is working.